# How do you get Gitlab Backup for Specific Repository

Tags: git, github, repository, gitlab, backup

I have made use of the following command to take backups:

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

The problem with the command is, it takes backup of all the repositories that currently exists which I do not want.

Say I have repositories for Project A and Project B among which I wish to take backup of all the repositories coming under Project A only.

Any clue how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#backup-adds-the-ability-to-skip-projects) (July 2023) should help:

> ### Backup adds the ability to skip projects
>
> The built-in [backup and restore](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html) tool adds the ability to skip specific repositories.
>
> The Rake task now accepts a list of comma-separated group or project paths to be skipped during the backup or restore by using the new `SKIP_REPOSITORIES_PATHS` environment variable.
> This will allow you to skip, for example, stale or archived projects which do not change over time, saving you
>
> - a) time by speeding up the backup run, and
> - b) space by not including this data in the backup file.
>
> Thanks to [Yuri Konotopov](https://gitlab.com/nE0sIghT) for this [community contribution](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/semgrep/-/merge_requests/196)!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_gitlab.html#back-up-specific-repositories) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18287).

Answer (score -2):

Backup the single rep, you should use the client methods:

```
git clone Url0fProjectA
```

For gitlab Metadata data of your project, you can also use the client's gitlab API to get.

more info of `gitlab API`, visit your `https://gitlburl/help/api/README.md`

Comment: Have you tried "clone and restore" method at your organization?? Does it help you to restore at the time when needed?? The restoration part is the one that I doubt would work for the above. Clone would simply make a copy of the git repo. and API execution would further complicate stuff. I found the "rake" mechanism to be efficient but just not sure about the filters needed to be added to skip the other unnecessary repositories.

Comment: The gitlab Rake support backup the different type data of the instance ，but does not filter the special rebo。more info please views your gitlab’s help doc：help/raketasks/backup_restore.md