# Create gitlab backup by skipping a project

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using GitLab, During backup i want a specific project to be skipped.
I tried
`sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=<project-name>`

but not possible to skip. Can any one correct where its getting wrong?

Comment: I think you can't skip specific repo, you could use "SKIP=repositories" but that will skip all the repositories. Check this - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18287

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't skip specific repo, you could use "SKIP=repositories" but that will skip all the repositories (projects).

Check this - gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18287

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 16.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/06/22/gitlab-16-1-released/#backup-adds-the-ability-to-skip-projects) (June 2023) extends that feature to multiple groups/projects:

> ### Backup adds the ability to skip projects
>
> The built-in [backup and restore](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html) tool adds the ability to skip specific repositories.
>
> The Rake task now accepts a list of comma-separated group or project paths to be skipped during the backup or restore by using the new `SKIP_REPOSITORIES_PATHS` environment variable.
> This will allow you to skip, for example, stale or archived projects which do not change over time, saving you
>
> - a) time by speeding up the backup run, and
> - b) space by not including this data in the backup file.
>
> Thanks to [Yuri Konotopov](https://gitlab.com/nE0sIghT) for this [community contribution](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/121865)!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_gitlab.html#back-up-specific-repositories) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18287).

See also [GitLab 16.2 "Backup adds the ability to skip projects"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76792471/6309).